# Vuejs Project is including typescript.js in production

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack

I am relatively new to the JS/TS world and am working on a VueJS project in typescript. The production version of the final app includes a 2.25mb typescript.js file. Can someone explain what this is for and if I can remove it?

[image: webpack-bundle-analyzer output]

Comment: it's typescript. It might be a silly question but did you `build` the application? Since TS is translated down to JS, I don't think you should have typescript files in your production code..

Comment: I did build using `vue-cli-service build --mode production --report` that's why I'm confused as to why it's in there